# How to call one Promise function from another Promise function in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise

I have one function that returns a Promise that needs to call another function that returns a Promise:

```
getUser(): Promise<User> {
    this.getAPIUser().then(result => {
        ..Do some stuff with result..
        return Promise.resolve(result);  // This doesn't work
    });
}

getAPIUser(): Promise<User> {
    return Promise.resolve({ firstName: 'Jason' });
}
```

I think this doesn't work since the getUser "return Promise.resolve" is in the context of the getAPIUser then handler. This was really easy in Angular 1, you would just instantiate a $q object and then resolve that object wherever you needed it. I can't figure out what the equivalent is in Angular 2/Typescript/EM6.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Aren't you just missing a return in getUser() ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `getUser` method doesn't return a promise at all.
When you invoke the `then` method on a promise it returns a `Promise` back and that is what your method needs to return:

```
getUser(): Promise<User> {
    return this.getAPIUser().then(result => {
        ..Do some stuff with result..
        return result;
    });
}
```

Comment: Sigh, yeah, I figured it out right after I posted but you guys were even faster than me! StackOverflow never ceases to amaze. I'll accept your answer in 6 minutes when it lets me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness this works as well:

```
getUser(): Promise<User> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        this.getAPIUser().then(user => {
            resolve(user);
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: This solution creates an extra `Promise` for now reason as your `getUser` function isn't asynced itself, it's only async because it calls the async `getAPIUser`

Comment: Ah, good point. Would this be the way to do it if getUser needed to return different information, or can the return in the promise from getAPIUser be changed?

Comment: The nice thing about the promises api is that they can be chained. So the `then` method returns a `Promise` on which you can `then` as well. What you return in one promise will be what the next one receives, so you can can in fact change what the chain results in.

Comment: Oh, gotcha! That makes a ton of sense, thanks Nitzan!